# How to show meta-box (with editor enabled) content on front-end

Tags: wordpress, editor, meta-boxes

I created meta-box with `wordpress` editor field. By this tutorial: https://imtiazrayhan.com/add-wysiwyg-editor-custom-meta-boxes/#comment-133

Everything okay, but in front-end I can't see same results like I filled on editor.

Example:

On editor:
I use paragraph, br

```
<p>Test</p></br>
<p>Test</p></br>
<p>Test</p></br>
```

So on editor everything is fine, but on my front-end I get:

> Test Test Test

It seems like this meta-box won't allow `p` and `br` tags or something like this...

I get my metabox on front with this:

```
$content = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_editor', true);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code to echo the content

```
$content = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_editor', true);
echo nl2br($content);
```